# Safe way to cast a uint16_t to a wchar_t

Tags: c++

Trying to clean up some code and i wanted to know if the following is a safe way to cast uint16_t to a wchar_t.

```
#if ! defined(MARKUP_SIZEOFWCHAR)
#if __SIZEOF_WCHAR_T__ == 4 || __WCHAR_MAX__ > 0x10000
#define MARKUP_SIZEOFWCHAR 4
#else
#define MARKUP_SIZEOFWCHAR 2
#endif

void FileReader::parseBuffer(char * buffer, int length)
{
  //start by looking for a vrsn
  //Header seek around for a vrns followed by 32 bit size descriptor
  //read 32 bits at a time
  int cursor = 0;
  char vrsn[5] = "vrsn";
  cursor = this->searchForMarker(cursor, length, vrsn, buffer);
  int32_t size = this->getObjectSizeForMarker(cursor, length, buffer);
  cursor = cursor + 7; //advance cursor past marker and size
  wchar_t *version = this->getObjectForSizeAndCursor(size, cursor, buffer);
  wcout << version;
  delete[] version; //this pointer is dest from getObjectForSizeAndCursor
}
```

-

```
wchar_t* FileReader::getObjectForSizeAndCursor(int32_t size, int cursor, char *buffer) {

  int wlen = size/2;
  uint32_t *dest = new uint32_t[wlen+1];
  unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)(buffer + cursor);
  for(int i=0; i<wlen; i++) {
    #if MARKUP_SIZEOFWCHAR == 4 // sizeof(wchar_t) == 4
      char padding[2] = {'\0','\0'}; 
      dest[i] =  (padding[0] << 24) + (padding[1] << 16) + (ptr[0] << 8) + ptr[1];
    #else // sizeof(wchar_t) == 2
      dest[i] = (ptr[0] << 8) + ptr[1];
    #endif
      ptr += 2;
      cout << ptr;
  }
  return (wchar_t *)dest;
}
```

do i have any scoping issues with the way i am using the padding? will i leak padding when i `delete dest[]` in the calling function?

Comment: In what environment is wchar_t 32 bits?  And what is he endianness of the two types you are converting between?

Comment: You're using a `uint32_t`, not a `uint16_t`. So which are you trying to do? Also, it's hard to tell what your code is trying to actually accomplish.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character according to that it could be 16 or 32. i read it other places also. they said on some windows systems it might be 32 bytes.

Comment: the code works fine, i just want to make sure 1) im not leaking anything, 2) if i need to add padding for the uint32_t

Comment: @j_mcnally Windows has 16-bit `wchar_t`, Linux and Mac have 32-bit `wchar_t` (except very old Mac, which was also 16-bit). That being said, I see absolutely no reason why directly casting a `uint16_t` to a `(unsigned) wchar_t` would ever present a problem on the Big Three.

Comment: thanks rubenvb, thats what i think i'll end up doing

Comment: `wchar_t` is only required to hold 8 bits, and it can be signed or unsigned. So any use of it for larger values is not portable. And while I'm on the subject, `uint16_t` and `uint32_t` are **not** required to exist. Unless your program requires **exactly** 16 or 32 bits, use `uint_least16_t` or `uint_fast16_t`, and `uint_least32_t` or `uint_fast32_t`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinction

```
#if MARKUP_SIZEOFWCHAR == 4 // sizeof(wchar_t) == 4
  char padding[2] = {'\0','\0'}; 
  dest[i] =  (padding[0] << 24) + (padding[1] << 16) + (ptr[0] << 8) + ptr[1];
#else // sizeof(wchar_t) == 2
  dest[i] = (ptr[0] << 8) + ptr[1];
#endif
```

is completely unnecessary. `padding[i]` is 0, so shifting that left keeps it 0, and adding it has no effect.

The compiler may or may not optimise the allocation of the two-byte array `padding` in each loop iteration away, but since it is an automatic array, it cannot leak in any way.

Since the types used in the loop are unsigned, simply using

```
dest[i] = (ptr[0] << 8) + ptr[1];
```

is perfectly safe. (The endianness must of course be correct.)

For

```
return (wchar_t *)dest;
```

you should let the type of `dest` depend on the size of `wchar_t`, it should be `uint16_t*` if `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2` (and `CHAR_BIT == 8`).

Comment: so theres no chance the memory at those 2 bytes would be anything other than 0?

Comment: Not unless the compiler is blatantly violating the specs.

Comment: oops should i also declare the uint16/32 depending on the sizeofwchar?

Comment: i feel like i over looked that, since on some systems it might be 16 bits.

Comment: Yes, using `uint16_t` or `uint32_t` depending on the size of `wchar_t` is something you should do. If `wchar_t` is 16 bits, using `uint32_t` would lead to many 0-characters (every other), and you don't want that.

Comment: so its safe to replace the code in your answer with just 'dest[i] = (ptr[0] << 8) + ptr[1];'

Comment: Yup, everything in the loop is unsigned, so there's no danger of undefined behaviour due to overflow.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't going to work. It's broken in several ways, but let's focus on the cast.

Your question doesn't match your code. Your code is using a `uint32_t`, while your question asks about a `uint16_t`. But that doesn't matter, because *neither will work*.

If you need to use `wchar_t`, then you should actually *use* `wchar_t`. If your goal is to take two consecutive bytes of a `char*` and copy them into the first-two bytes of a `wchar_t`, then just do that.

Here is a much better version of your code, one that actually *works* (to the degree that it makes sense to copy two bytes from a `char*` and pretend that it's a `wchar_t`):

```
std::wstring FileReader::getObjectForSizeAndCursor(int32_t size, int cursor, char *buffer) {

  int wlen = size/2;
  std::wstring out(wlen);
  unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)(buffer + cursor);
  for(int i=0; i<wlen; i++) {
    out[i] = (ptr[0] << 8) + ptr[1];
    ptr += 2;
    cout << ptr;
  }
  return out;
}
```

Plus, there's no chance of memory leaking since we're using a proper RAII class like `std::wstring`.